# How to set all in 1 line

Tags: php, css

I have made a dashboard where i have logo at the left side project name in the middle & links to the right.I have used used absolute value to get all of them on one line & did it on screen resolution 1366 x 768. But when i checked it on screen resolution 1024 x 768 it overlapped. Please Help.

```
<style>
#heading{ text-align:right;font-size: 20px;float:right;margin:50px 20px;}
#img{ margin:10px 10px; }
</style>
<body>
<a href="homepage.php"><img id="img" src="LOGO.jpg" width="150px" height="100px"></a>
<h1 align="center" style="position:absolute;top:30px; left:500px;">MEETING ROOM DETAILS</h1>
<div id="heading"><a href="homepage.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['usr_name']); ?></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="changepswd.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Change Password</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Logout</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="UserManual.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Help</a></div>
```

Comment: Show full code with jsFiddle link replicating the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Sir this part of code is working fine in screen resolution 1366 x 768. But when i change the screen resolution to 1024 x 768 all the headers get overlapped.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle as mentioned above? The code you mentioned above looks nothing more than a junk if not presented meaningfully. If you are looking for clear answers, first make your questions clear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ankit_Kansara/aq73nfrp/embedded/result/ In this fiddle the links are coming below where originally it should be on right side & when i change the screen resolution the title & link overlaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your elements into child `header-section` element and into a parent `header` element. You can then use `display: inline-block` to display them all on the same line.

EDIT:
Lets start with getting the structure right. You want a header that is split into 3 parts all displaying on the same line. This can be achieved using the following:

```css
#header
{
  width:100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.small-section
{
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.large-section
{
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="small-section" style="background: rgb(255,0,0);">LOGO</div>
  <div class="large-section" style="background: rgb(0,255,0);">TITLE</div>
  <div class="small-section" style="background: rgb(0,0,255);">LINKS</div>
</div>
```

This will create a header that will span the full width of the page unless the window size is less the 1000px in which case it stays at width 1000px and a scroll bar will appear at the bottom.

It has two small sections which are at least 250px wide and always 25% of the full header.

It also has one large section in the middle which is at least 500px wide and always 50% of the full header

Comment: Sir didn't get the desired result

Comment: edited my code to try and fix

Answer (score 0):

create main division and put your this code in main division. set whit with and height of main division to 100% `style = "width:100%; height:"as you want";`. percentage with automatically adjust for all resolution.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand. Can you please explain